# What happens to events written after a checkpoint?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

I have a bunch of summary nodes (scalars, histograms, etc) that are constantly writing to the log. Checkpointing is not as frequent, and so I often have situations in which I'm recovering from a checkpoint that is earlier than the events that have been written to the log. When I resume from the checkpoint and start writing to the log again, what exactly happens? Do the old events get overwritten? The documentation is not very clear on this. Looking in TensorBoard, it appears as if the "future" events are still there. Ideally I'd like to flush everything ahead of the current `global_step` and just start over.

Answer (score 1):

TensorBoard does have logic to handle this case - it looks for restart events, and tries to purge everything with a global_step greater than the restart step. [See this code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r0.7/tensorflow/python/summary/event_accumulator.py#L310). If you are still seeing the orphaned events, that means something isn't working - maybe the SessionLog.START event isn't being written when your job restarts from checkpoint?

Can you create a simple repro of this and file an issue on GitHub?